# Matrix Multiplication of NxM in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have 2 matrices in Python: Matrix A of shape (4,1) and Matrix B of shape(4,4).
I formed the 2 matrices using the data in a list.

valList data looks like

```
00200030
00200030
00200030
00200030
00480051
FFF0004B
FFF0004B
```

I converted each item into a 32 bit integer and then used the data to form the matrices.

```
for item in valList:
    int(item,32)

B_RC = createMatrix(rows,1,valList)
B = np.array(B_RC)
print B

A_RC = valList[rows:rows + (rows * cols)]
A = np.array(A_RC).reshape( (rows,cols))
print A

def createMatrix(rowCount, colCount, dataList):   
    mat = []
    for i in range (rowCount):
        rowList = []
        for j in range (colCount):
            if dataList[j] not in mat:
                rowList.append(dataList[i])
        mat.append(rowList)

    return mat
```

I want to multiply both the matrices.
I used numpy, but I get the following error for the code below:

```
>>> C=np.matmul(B,A)

error: ufunc 'matmul' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('S8') dtype('S8') dtype('S8')
```

What function should i use?

Comment: I think the problem lies within the data type of your `A` and `B` matrices.. Could you post their values in the question please?

Comment: I'm assuming that `dataList` have all numbers, then you need to change the data type of your numpy array like so `A = A.astype("float64")` and `B = B.astype("float64")` before running `C`

Comment: I tried this...it gives me could not convert string to float: My data item in the list is for example FFBCFFA2

Comment: So, how are you willing to perform a dot-product over strings?

Comment: How do i convert a list of strings into a hex number 32 bit?

Comment: You can use `int("FFBCFFA2", 32)` to convert your hex-values into a number. Anyway, I've added an example to my answer to explain how the whole process should be going.

Answer (score 0):

Python has operators for these use-cases:

```
A * B  # dot-product
A @ B  # matrix-multiplication
```

The matrix multiplication operator is right-associative.

If you need those as function arguments:

```
import operator
operator.matmul(A, B)
```

Comment: I don't think this answer tackles the users error since the error they get when they used `matmul` is " error: ufunc 'matmul' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('S8') dtype('S8') dtype('S8') "

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, matrix `A` and `B` have hex-decimal values of base 32 written as `str`. And to perform a dot product, we need first to convert these values into integers using the built-in function `int(value, base)`.

Here, I've created a small example to explain how the process should go:

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> A = np.array([[int("FFBCFFA2", 32)],
                  [int("FFBCFFA2", 32)],
                  [int("FFBCFFA2", 32)],
                  [int("FFBCFFA2", 32)]])
>>> A.shape
(4,1)
>>>
>>> B = np.array([[int("FFBCFFA2", 32), int("FFBCFFA2", 32), int("FFBCFFA2", 32), int("FFBCFFA2", 32)],
                  [int("FFBCFFA2", 32), int("FFBCFFA2", 32), int("FFBCFFA2", 32), int("FFBCFFA2", 32)],
                  [int("FFBCFFA2", 32), int("FFBCFFA2", 32), int("FFBCFFA2", 32), int("FFBCFFA2", 32)],
                  [int("FFBCFFA2", 32), int("FFBCFFA2", 32), int("FFBCFFA2", 32), int("FFBCFFA2", 32)]])
>>> B.shape
(4,4)
>>>
>>> C = np.matmul(A, B)
[[6956274410837382160]
 [6956274410837382160]
 [6956274410837382160]
 [6956274410837382160]]
```

As we can see, the output of the dot product is numbers, you can convert these back to hex values using `hex()` method:

```
>>> hex(C[0][0])
0x6089a6b8821a1410
```

### EDIT

The following is the correct way to convert your `valList` into `int`:

```
valList = list(map(lambda x: int(x,32), valList))
```

Comment: I updated my query...i did try to change the list to 32bit before using the form matrix functions, error seems to remain the same..can you have a look at the updated code?